# MapRouteFinder doesn't work for walking routes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working with a `MapRouteFinder` class. It is supposed to find a route between two `Geopoint`'s.

If I try to find a route with a `GetDrivingRouteAsync()` function, everything works just fine. The problem is that very often, when I call the `GetWalkingRouteAsync()`, the `MapRouteFinderResult.Status` happens to be `UnknownError`. It's not really informative, and I have idea what might be the problem.

Here's the sample code that results with `UnknownError`:

```
Geopoint point1 = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
{
    Latitude = 45.461037,
    Longitude = 9.20262
});

Geopoint point2 = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
{
    Latitude = 45.459506037577,
    Longitude = 9.1983944177628
});

var routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteAsync(point1, point2);
```

Do you know what can cause this problem? I obtain geocoordinates via the `Geolocator`, so they shound't make any problems, should they? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are these locations too far away of too close to each other maybe? What happens when you use different locations? I tried two random Seattle locations and it worked OK.

Comment: Some of them works fine (e.g. different city). These locations are rather close to each other - after all I want to acquire walking route (I want to get ~500m route, not a 5km). I'm mostly testing these feature in Milan city. What bothers me is that I don't get `NoRouteFound` or sth like that. It's just `UnknownError`..

Answer (score 0):

Almost 4 years later, I faced exactly the same issue. After few days of head scratching, I came to know that there is another Microsoft API which brings the required information. It's BINGMapsRESTToolKit! I added this to my UWP app project through Nuget Manager and used the following code and it worked!

```
var req = new RouteRequest()
{
 BingMapsKey = [YOUR BING MAPS KEY],
 Waypoints = new List<SimpleWaypoint>()
 {
  new SimpleWaypoint(latitude1,longitude1),
  new SimpleWaypoint(latitude2,longitude2)
 },
 RouteOptions = new RouteOptions()
 {
  TravelMode = TravelModeType.Walking
 },
};
var response = await req.Execute();
var stopDistance =(((BingMapsRESTToolkit.Route)response.ResourceSets.FirstOrDefault().Resources.FirstOrDefault()).TravelDistance);
```

Hope it helps someone...